# Using MvcMiniProfiler in combination with Telerik RadAjaxPanel in webforms

Tags: .net, asp.net-ajax, telerik, mvc-mini-profiler

We are using [MvcMiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) in a webforms project, and so far we're very pleased with it.

We also make heavy usage of the [Telerik ajax controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx), and we have a problem with the profiler when combined with RadAjaxPanels. For instance, we have a usercontrol wrapped in an ajaxpanel. Upon the first load, profiled code is recognized and loaded in the profiler,  but on subsequent partial postbacks, the profiler does not get updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, but perhaps would need to log as a bug on the project site. We don't actively use those controls, so I don't know (without looking) what the conflict is.

Comment: I have, http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=75
Just asking whether someone else has this issue, and for posterity.

Comment: my guess is that there is some sort of caching going on

Comment: At first i thought it might have been that the Telerik controls were built on top of their own ajax framework and needed a fix like the one I pushed (http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=52) but it appears that their controls are built on top of the MS Ajax Framework so my fix should handle it.